# python: get global position of parented/constrained object

Tags: python, constraints, drivers, parent

I'm trying to find a solution to [this other question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65460/project-2d-motion-track-onto-a-sphere) I have.

How can I get the global position of an object, that is either parented to another object (i.e. the child's global position) or has its position controlled by a constraint. (like "Follow Track")

The resulting Data should be usable in a script or a driver.

This seems simple, but I can't find a way to achieve this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `obj.matrix_world.to_translation()`